# Docbook to PDF (with tables and etc)

Tags: pdf, docbook

Please suggest me an offline tool for `Docbook->Pdf` conversion. The docbook document contains a lot of tables(which can't be rendered correctly to `pdf` with `Apache FOP` based tools. The message `"table layout auto isn't implemented"` is appeared and (as result I think) some tables has text in columns overlapped).

I've found quite useful tool `http://docbookpublishing.com/` but it works only online.

`docbook2pdf` won't convert, with message appeared(`"jade:/usr/share/sgml/docbook/dsssl-stylesheets/print/dbtable.dsl:372:10:E: 1st argument for primitive "string->number" of wrong type: "#f" not a string"`) which is hard to understand without deep investigation.

Haskell `pandoc` tool, was tested also but I didn't understand the actual function of this tool(as I understood it only converts `Docbook->latex` and than `pdflatex` used). Document converted with pandoc looks odd(pages order is changed, table of contents is missed) and has worse rendered quality than others. I didn't find quick way to customize it.

Comment: The engine behind http://docbookpublishing.com is [XEP](http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html). There are free versions available for non-commercial use. XEP Desktop [costs $360](http://www.renderx.com/download/shop.html).

Comment: You can customize the appearance of pandoc's PDF output by using a custom latex template -- see pandoc documentation for details.  Generate a default template using `pandoc -D latex > my.latex`, then modify the template and use it with the `--template my.latex` option.  Pandoc's docbook reader is not complete, and in any case some information will be lost, as pandoc's internal format is less expressive than docbook. Note that you can get an automatic table of contents using the `--toc` option; that is why the docbook table of contents is skipped.

Comment: There's also [dblatex](https://dblatex.sourceforge.net)... but from what you're saying, you are looking at a somewhat broken DocBook input, and no kind of converter works well with that.